# Unable to open libpenguin.so: dlopen failed: library "libpenguin.so" not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build Unity in Android Studio by integrating Android Studio and Unity.

I used an example from GitHub called uaal example (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/uaal-example/22LTS/docs/android.md).

Upon checking the log using logcat, it says that it cannot find the file called libpenguin.so.

After checking all the files on my computer, I found that the file libpenguin.so does not exist.

I used Google AR Core, AR Foundation, and XR Package Management in Unity on a Mac environment, and currently, I'm building Unity by linking Unity and Android Studio on Windows 10.

I'm wondering if there is a possibility that the libpenguin.so file could be missing when transferring a Unity project made in a Mac environment to Windows 10.

Also, I'm curious about how the error was fixed by replacing the non-existing libpenguin.so in some way.

Additionally, when I build by linking Android Studio and Unity, the UI appears, but the AR screen is entirely black. I'm curious if fixing the error regarding the libpenguin.so file could also fix this black screen issue.

Used Versions
Unity: 2022.3.4f1
Android Studio: 2022 version
SDK: Same version as Unity
NDK: Same version as Unity

jinlibs

[image: Picture 1]

logcat
[image: Picture 2]

I'm not sure where and how the error is occurring, so I can't post the code. If there's any specific code you need, please let me know, and I'll provide it.

Thank you.

I transferred the Unity project to a Windows 10 environment and tried to build it anew to check if the problem arises when building from Unity to Android. -> But the error continued to occur.

I tried copying and pasting the libpenguin.so file from another external GitHub file, but the error still occurred.

To fix the issue of the black screen continuously appearing, I tried building using the uaal ar example, but the black screen still appears.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same error in the logs for the app we develop. It was happening in a Samsung Galaxy device but not in a Pixel. The developers where I work believe it can be safely ignored as harmless.